# Stack Overflow interesting questions implementation

Tags: discussion, interesting-page

According to the tooltip of the 'interesting' tab, interesting questions are

> "questions that may be of interest to you based on your history and tag preferences"

Does Stack Overflow use a recommendation engine or just some sql sort/filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

In short, first drop any topics you ignored or attract low-attention, then apply the scoring formula:

- your interesting tags    +1,500 per interesting tag, up to +2,000 total
- your top 40 scoring tags maximum of +1,000 per tag (scaled), up to +2,000 total
- question score   +200 × score, up to +1,000 total
- total answer score   -200 × score, up to -1,000 total
- number of answers    -200 × answers, up to -1,000 total
- number of views  -15 × views, up to -1,000 total
- question last activity date  -1 × (seconds / 15)

Those make 90% of the interesting questions. The other 10% comes from some random pick.

It's a simple but effective solution.

Comment: Hi! I wonder whether it is still the same algorithm now (in 2019)? Thanks!