# What does the Home Screen do that the Question Screen doesn't?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, responsive-design

I'm one of the folks that don't like the left nav bar (hanging out mostly on EESE).  I tried hiding it, but notice that I constantly need to hit the "Questions" choice.

If I just click on the site name, I get sent to a home page, with a limited "Top Questions" list.  I suggest that this page has very little, if anything, that's not on the "Questions" page, and is simply fairly useless.  I don't see anything on the  Electrical Engineering Home Page that's of help to any user, old or new, that's not on the Questions page in a more useful form.

Why not get rid of the Home Page?  That way, I have a Questions button (the main site link) and I can hide the silly Left Nav bar with impunity.

Answer (score 6):

The Home Page doesn't show questions with a score [lower than or equal to -4 (-8 on meta sites)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99932). Also, on larger sites (such as Stack Overflow), there's an algorithm that [tends to show you questions which you are likely able to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152527/295232) (because you've answered questions with that tag before). Its purpose is to show you recently active questions which might be interesting to you (in fact, the tab is called "interesting" rather than "active"). As @Sonic notes in the comments, it has a [live update feature](/questions/125677) as well.

On the other hand, the Questions page is a starting point to browse through *all* questions on the site, so it has a different purpose.

The only option I currently see for you is to bookmark the Questions page, or install the following userscript that transforms the link in the logo:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Let Logo Link to Questions page
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    $("a.site-header--link").each(function() { $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + "/questions"); })
});
```

Comment: Also note that the homepage has a live WebSocket connection for questions with new activity, while the Questions page doesn't.

Comment: ... or, add a "newest" option to the home page horizontal menu, and a next page mechanism on the bottom, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why remove that sentence?

Comment: Because I was reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox?rq=1) which claims it also works on the 'newest' page.

Comment: Thanks for the user script, but I use web sites, I don't monkey with them.  I just don't think scripts are in a solution path for the typical user.

Comment: @ScottSeidman "newest" would imply newest questions; the front page shows you newest *activity*, with filtering.

Comment: Then what does "Top Questions" mean??  Newest questions that are higher than -4 passed through (or maybe not, depending on site) an interest algorithm?